# OS Error: No such file or directory, error no = 2 -- FLUTTER

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter, mobile-application

In my flutter project, I wanna get a list of all the files that I have in a directory named ".../myApp/services".

```
Widget getServices(){
Directory dir = Directory("services");
print(dir.absolute);
dir.list().listen(
  (FileSystemEntity file) {
    services.add(FileImage(file));
  }
);
```

}

However with this code, the output in debug console is this:

[image]

It prints the absolute path, and then gives this error. I don't get it... is the path valid or not?

Answer (score 3):

you have to register your directory in pubspec.yaml

[image]

step 2

-use [this plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/global_configuration) to scan pubspecs.yaml to get your assets

Comment: I have already added my directory to the pubspecs.yaml but I still had the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's two different things here. First up, you can create a `Directory` object for a path that doesn't (yet) exist on disk. This is so that you can create the directory. See the documentation for the [`Directory` class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-io/Directory-class.html).

Secondly, Android has some implicit structure about where you are allowed to read from and write to disk. See the Android documentation [on data storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage).

Comment: No, I wanna access that directory on my pc

Comment: hi @Brett I have the same problem. Could you please check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433782/how-to-read-xml-files-in-flutter