# How to read XML files in flutter?

Tags: xml, flutter

I am trying to read the XML file in my flutter. But every time I try to read the file, it only throws an error.

This is where I read the xml file(My XML file is large).

```
convertXMLtoJSON() async {
File file = File('assets/xml_file/belovedskincare.xml');
Future<String> xml = file.readAsString();
}
```

And when I run this, it throws this error.

```
E/flutter (13956): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/xml_file/belovedskincare.xml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I have also tried some other functions like

```
file.readAsLines();
file.readAsStringSync();
```

But nothing changed.

this is my pubspec.yaml

[image]

The assets are working fine. You can see the file structure on the left side in the second image.

[image]

I have also tried the `rootbundle` but its not working as well.

```
convertXMLtoJSON() async {
String file = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/xml_file/belovedskincare.xml');
print(file);
}
```

when I run this one, it shows this error.

```
E/flutter (13956): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

Answer (score 2):

For the AssetBundle, you have to add the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` line in the main class.

This is my main class,

```
    void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FetchData a = FetchData();
  a.data();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This is where I load my XML file,

```
    class FetchData {
  data() async {
    print(await rootBundle.loadString("assets/xml_file/belovedskincare.xml"));
  }
}
```

If you want to convert the XML file to JSON, you can use the [xml2json package](https://pub.dev/packages/xml2json).

```
class FetchData {
  data() async {  
  final xml = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/xml_file/belovedskincare.xml");
  Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
  xml2json.parse(xml);
  var json = xml2json.toGData();
  print(json);
  }
}
```

As for the `file.readAsString();`, I am still trying to figure out the problem.

```
    convertXMLtoJSON() async {
File file = File('assets/xml_file/belovedskincare.xml');
Future<String> xml = file.readAsString();  // this is where the error happens
}
```

You can also use the localhost to read the file(I am using XAMPP). Place the XML file inside the **htdocs** directory and use the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to read the file.
For WAMP, place the file inside the **www** directory.

This is my code,
Replace the **localhost** in the URL with your IP address. Type `ipconfig` in your command prompt to get your IP address(IPv4 Address).

And use the [xml2json package](https://pub.dev/packages/xml2json) to convert the XML file to JSON format.

```
    final jsonData =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('http://localhost/file_name'));
  final xml = jsonData.body;
  Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
  xml2json.parse(xml);
  var json = xml2json.toGData();
  print(json);
  var response = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(json));
  print(response);
```