# Flutter can't seem to find a Json file from relative path

Tags: flutter, file-management

I apologise in advance if this is a silly question, but I have created a file and stored it in my "assets" sub-directory, which is at the same level as my lib directory and my pubspec.yaml file. I've set the relative path to "assets/ExerData.json" in my code (see below).

When I run the code saved as a scratch.dart file as shown below, hitched up to a Galaxy Nexus API 29 emulator, it can only tell me "Can't find file!"

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

String filePath = "assets/ExerData.json";

void main() {
  performTasks();
}

void performTasks() {
  if (checkFileExists(filePath)) {
    readFile(filePath);
  } else {
    print("Can't find file");
  }
}

bool checkFileExists(path) {
  bool result = File(path).existsSync();
  print(result.toString());
  return result;
}

Future<String> readFile(path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
}
```

I populated my pubspec.yaml file with this entry:

```
assets:
  - assets/ExerData.json
```

I expected it to find my file, read it using rootbundle.loadstring(path), and print out the resulting string to the console.

As I say, all it did was print "Can't find file".

I'd very much appreciate you help on this one!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this link; it's similar to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757953/how-to-load-json-assets-into-a-flutter-app

Answer (score 0):

The `rootBundle` contains the resources that were packaged with the app when it was built. All files specified under `assets:` in your `pubspec` are packaged with the app. You can check if file exists by wrapping `rootBundle.loadString()` inside `try{} catch(){}` block.

```
  Future<bool> fileExists(String path) async {
    try {
      await rootBundle.loadString(path);
    } catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

or

```
  Future<String?> loadFile(String path) async {
    try {
      return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
    } catch (_) {
      // File not found Exception
      return null;
    }
  }
```

File is a dart class. It needs absolute or relative path of the file being read.
You can use `File` with  `path_provider` to get the absolute path from the current File System.

For example on Android:

```
 Future<void> getPath() async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    print('PATH IS : $appDocPath');
  }
```

prints

> `'/data/user/0/com.soliev.file_demo/app_flutter'`

Comment: After a little more bug tracing a little more upstream in the program logic, I discovered that the binding had not been initialised.  I added
"WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();"
to the first line of the main function and it suddenly started to work.  There is probably a good reason why "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();" was not necessary in my actual app (as opposed to my scratch.dart code), but I'm not sure what that reason is.

Comment: Thank you very much for you kind help! I've learnt a good deal from it, though not necessarily to resolve this particular problem. In particular, the option of using the pathProvider method is likely to be useful to me in the future!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/ExerData.json");
final jsonResult = jsonDecode(data);
```

Reference: [How to load JSON assets into a Flutter App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757953/how-to-load-json-assets-into-a-flutter-app)

Comment: Thank you very much for you kind help! I've learnt a good deal from it, though not necessarily to resolve this particular problem. I intend to experiment with the default DefaultAssetBundle class during the course of the day!
Thanks again! I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the program logic had not completed initializing the necessary binding.

I called the method `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` in the first line of the main class and everything started working as I expected.

Thanks to everyone who looked at my question!

Here's a similar question involving binding with XML files:
[How to read XML files in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433782/how-to-read-xml-files-in-flutter/69451990#69451990)